# Flutter jitsi-meet error Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.3.0

Tags: flutter, dart, jitsi-meet

I am getting this issue when trying to run the app . i have follow all steps from official docs
here is the  [link](https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet)
`

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :jitsi_meet
      > Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.3.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/3.3.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-3.3.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/master/releases/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/3.3.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-3.3.0.pom'.      
               > Connect to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 [raw.githubusercontent.com/49.44.79.236, raw.githubusercontent.com/2405:200:1607:2820:41:0:0:36] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

`

this is my app build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.jitspi_pro"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 2
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            // useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

i have created seprate project for only jitsi-meet but still getting same error again and again

Answer (score 0):

try this code in the manifest.xml

```
<service
  android:name="org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService"
       android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"
  android:exported="true">

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```